# Point-in-polygon using Python and OGR

Tags: python, ogr, point-in-polygon, osgeo

I want to use OGR in Python to write a simple point-in-polygon test:

```
def point_in_polygon(point, polygon):
    """
    point : [longitude, latitude]

    polygon : [(lon1, lat1), (lon2, lat2), ..., (lonn, latn)]

    """
    # Create spatialReference
    spatialReference = osgeo.osr.SpatialReference()
    spatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84")
    # Create ring
    ring = osgeo.ogr.Geometry(osgeo.ogr.wkbLinearRing)
    # Add points
    for lon, lat in polygon:
        ring.AddPoint(lon, lat)
    # Create polygon
    poly = osgeo.ogr.Geometry(osgeo.ogr.wkbPolygon)
    poly.AssignSpatialReference(spatialReference)
    poly.AddGeometry(ring)
    # Create point
    pt = osgeo.ogr.Geometry(osgeo.ogr.wkbPoint)
    pt.AssignSpatialReference(spatialReference)
    pt.SetPoint(0, point[0], point[1])
    # test
    return pt.Within(poly)
```

However, it doesn't seem to work properly:

```
In [22]: polygon = [(-10., -10.), (-10., 10.), (10., 10.), (10., -10.), (-10., -10.)]

In [23]: point_in_polygon([0., 0.], polygon)
Out[23]: True

In [24]: point_in_polygon([359., 0.], polygon)
Out[24]: False
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect it's because the underlying [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) library only work in Cartesian space rather than spherical, so you'll have to subtract 360 from any longitudinal coordinate greater than 180, which makes 359 == -1. Of course, you'll still have problems with features crossing the anti-meridian (i.e. +- 180 degrees longitude), but you can easily detect that and not do the 360 subtraction step.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. It strikes me as odd that something having "geospatial" in its name doesn't cover these simple geo-applications. Any other idea how I can solve the point-in-polygon in Python without having to consider those cases manually?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment if you are looking for pure code rather using OGR package, there are many good links such as [**this: in C**](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/insidepoly/) and [**this: in Python**](http://www.ariel.com.au/a/python-point-int-poly.html) which directly address your problem by pure codes. You may find even more by googling;)

Comment: thanks, but those links don't take into account that the Earth is a sphere.